# Implementing React Native In App Billing for Android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, react-native

I'm trying to add In App Purchase for Play Store using [react-native-billing](https://github.com/idehub/react-native-billing) but don't know how to do it.

Google can't seem to find any tutorial for In App Billing

I have seen the [example](https://github.com/idehub/react-native-billing/blob/master/example/index.android.js) which looks like this

```
InAppBilling.open()
        .then(() => InAppBilling.purchase('android.test.purchased'))
        .then((details) => {
            this.setState({
                purchaseText: details.productId
            });
            return InAppBilling.getProductDetails('android.test.purchased');
        })
        .then((productDetails) => {
            this.setState({
                productDetailsText: productDetails.title
            });
            return InAppBilling.close();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({
                error: error
            });
        });
```

which is quite simple. But what I don't understand  is `android.test.purchased`

Maybe that's bcz of my lack of knowledge about In App purchases on Android

I also don't get what is `details` & `productDetails` & where to implement them

How to implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read what was written in `In App Products` dropdown. It was written `To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK.` Now I can implement.

Answer (score 0):

`android.test.purchased` is a way to test in-app purchases for debugging purposes (Further ressources: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html).

Comment: How do we get `details` in `then` ?